# Validate file extensions in Apex

Tags: visualforce, apex

End user can upload files in a Visualforce page. In the backend I need to create a list of allowed file extensions, and restrict the user to that list.  How do I create the extensions list and validate it? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need apex for that?

[`<apex:inputFile>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputFile.htm) has `accept` parameter which you can use. Bear in mind this will check [contentType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), not extension (which is bit more proper way to do it).

If you still want the validation in apex - probably something like this?

```
String fileName = 'foobar.xls';
Set<String> acceptedExtensions = new Set<String> {'.doc','.txt', '.jpg'};

Boolean found = false;
for(String s : acceptedExtensions){
    if(found = fileName.endsWith(s)){ // yes, there's only one "=", I do want assignment here
        break;
    }
}
if(!found){ // after the whole loop it's still false?
    ApexPages.addMessage(...);
}
```